# Sorting a 2D Vector by its Date Column

Tags: c++, sorting, printing, 2d-vector

I am trying to sort and print a 2D vector by its Date, which is stored in a column in the format of DD-MM-YYYY. I have a 'preload' tickets stored as string and would first looped through it to get the tickets by ***Username***.

From there, I would print push back the User's tickets into a 2d vector before sorting and printing them. The error I'm getting after typing username *'kaya'* for instance, is:
**Debug Asertion Failed! Expression: vector subscript out of range**
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG8C3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG8C3.png)

Even when I print out the vector without sorting, the results are still weird, so I am not sure whether  it is because I am pushing back wrongly, affecting the sorting as well. Here is the weird output I mean:

```
*Search Ticket by Username
kaya
invalid. Please try again
2       RM40.0  10      15      3       5       2       kaya    15-10-2020      09:30   10:00
6       RM5.0   5       2       3       4       2       kaya    23-06-2022      08:30   09:30

2
RM40.0
10
15
3
5
2
kaya
15-10-2020
09:30
10:00
6
RM5.0
5
2
3
4
2
kaya
23-06-2022
08:30
09:30

C:\Users\Kar Yee\source\repos\DSTR_KyTest\Debug\DSTR_KyTest.exe (process 4044) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .*
```

My full code and what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm> // for sort()


string defaultTickets[][11] =
//ticket_id, total_amount,total_distance, total_travelTime,departure_station_id,
//arrival_station_id, user_id, user_name, date, estimated_departure_time, estimated_arrival_time
{
{"1", "RM20.0", "20", "30", "1", "5", "1", "bob", "10-10-2022", "08:30", "10:30"},
{"2", "RM40.0", "10", "15", "3", "5", "2", "kaya", "15-10-2020", "09:30", "10:00"},
{"3", "RM25.0", "5", "10", "5", "6", "1", "bob", "10-05-2022", "11:30", "012:30"},
{"5", "RM30.0", "13", "40", "1", "6", "4", "zhen Hou", "23-05-2022", "08:00", "09:00"},
{"6", "RM5.0", "5", "2", "3", "4", "2", "kaya", "23-06-2022", "08:30", "09:30"},
{"7", "RM8.0", "8", "4", "1", "3", "4", "zhen Hou", "20-05-2022", "08:45", "09:00"},
{"8", "RM10.0", "3", "10", "4", "6", "1", "bob", "10-05-2022", "09:00", "10:00"},

};


bool SortDateColumn(const std::vector<std::string>& a1,
    const std::vector<std::string>& a2)
{
    return atoi(a1[8].c_str()) > atoi(a2[8].c_str());  
}


int main() {

    int num_col = 10;
    int num_row = 7;
    string search_user = "";


    // declare 2D vector
    vector< vector<string>> ticketVector(num_row, vector<string>(num_col));  //preset row and columns
    //vector< vector<string>> ticketVector();
    int size = *(&defaultTickets + 1) - defaultTickets;

    
    bool valid = false;
    cout << "Search Ticket by Username" << endl;
    cin >> search_user;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (search_user == defaultTickets[i][7])
        {
            /*cout << "Ticket ID\t Amount Paid\t Distance\t TravelTime \tDeparture_station_id \t Arrival_station_id \tUserID \t Username" << "";
            cout << "\tdate \testimated_departure_time \testimated_arrival_time" << "\n";*/
            for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
            {
                cout << defaultTickets[i][x] << "\t";
                
                ticketVector.push_back({ defaultTickets[i][x] });
                valid = true;

            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (valid == false)
        {
            cout << "invalid. Please try again" << endl;
        }
        
    }





    //sort(ticketVector[8].begin(), ticketVector[8].end());
    

    /*std::sort (ticketVector.begin(), ticketVector.end(), [](value& a, value& b)->bool { return a.date < b.date; });
    for (auto& x : ticketVector) cout << x.date << endl;
    return 0;*/

     //Sort the data using the first column of each `std::vector<std::string>` as the criteria
    std::sort(ticketVector.begin(), ticketVector.end(), SortDateColumn);

    //print vector
    for (int i = 0;i < ticketVector.size();i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < ticketVector[i].size();j++)
            cout << ticketVector[i][j] << "";
        cout << endl;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: The `atoi` function does not magically convert DD-MM-YYYY strings into a date-related value. What it will _actually_ do is parse the string until it reaches the end of something that looks like an integer. The result will be you'll only be comparing the day value. The comparison used in your sort predicate will order in reverse, and the result will be sorting the data from the highest day number to the lowest.

Comment: It simply says "Exception Thrown: DSTR_KyTest.exe has triggered a breakpoint."  and points  to a set of automatically generated code

Comment: Okay, great start. So look at the call stack and walk back to the part that's your own code. Now you know where your code crashes, and you can then run your program up to that point, examining its state step by step.

Comment: Reproducing the crash: https://godbolt.org/z/aqEs4d4Er -- here the call stack points to a bad pointer in your `SortDateColumn` function. Well, that's suspiciously like an out-of-bounds access. So, changing the function to use `std::vector::at` instead confirms that indeed the vector is not the size you thought it is: https://godbolt.org/z/6ejYeG6q8

Comment: is there possibly an alternative method to sort by the date column?

Comment: Yes, but right now that's not even the main problem. Your biggest issue is `ticketsVector` does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your dates conform to the format DD-MM-YYYY, they can be lexographically ordered if you just rearrange the characters to YYYYMMDD. However, you typically want to avoid any kind of dynamic allocation or copying (*e.g.* rebuilding a string every time) as part of a sorting operation.

So, you can achieve this by combining [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) with [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). You can use the string_view to acquire the relevant substrings, and put them in the correct order with a tuple. The tuple supports ordering already.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>

using std::string_view;
using std::tuple;

typedef tuple<string_view, string_view, string_view> DateView;

DateView YYYYMMDD(const string& s)
{
    if (s.size() != 10 || s[2] != '-' || s[5] != '-')
        return {};

    return DateView{
        string_view(s.c_str() + 6, 4),  // YYYY
        string_view(s.c_str() + 3, 2),  // MM
        string_view(s.c_str() + 0, 2)   // DD
    };
}

// Returns true if date 'a' is less than date 'b'
bool CompareDate(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    return YYYYMMDD(a) < YYYYMMDD(b);
}
```

Now you have the basis for sorting. Since you want to sort dates in reverse, you can just invert the result of the `CompareDate` function:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> dates = {
        "10-10-2022",
        "15-10-2020",
        "10-05-2022",
        "23-05-2022",
        "23-06-2022",
        "20-05-2022",
        "10-05-2022",
    };

    std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(),
        [](const string& a, const string& b) { return !CompareDate(a, b); });

    for (const auto& date : dates)
    {
        cout << date << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

As for your actual construction of the vector to begin with, it's a bit of a shambles. You are pushing a single element onto `ticketsVector` whenever you match the name. As a result, you access these vectors out of bounds later on when you assume they hold an entire row.

Instead of copying the tickets into a new vector, why not actually create them as a vector to begin with? You can reference a ticket by its row index instead of copying. You may also want to use enums to identify columns instead of magic hard-coded numbers.

```
enum Column
{
    kTicketId, kTotalAmount, kTotalDistance, kTotalTravelTime,
    kDepartureStationId, kArrivalStationId, kUserId, kUserName,
    kDate, kEstimatedDepartureTime, kEstimatedArrivalTime
};

vector<vector<string>> defaultTickets =
{
    {"1", "RM20.0", "20", "30", "1", "5", "1", "bob", "10-10-2022", "08:30", "10:30"},
    {"2", "RM40.0", "10", "15", "3", "5", "2", "kaya", "15-10-2020", "09:30", "10:00"},
    {"3", "RM25.0", "5", "10", "5", "6", "1", "bob", "10-05-2022", "11:30", "012:30"},
    {"5", "RM30.0", "13", "40", "1", "6", "4", "zhen Hou", "23-05-2022", "08:00", "09:00"},
    {"6", "RM5.0", "5", "2", "3", "4", "2", "kaya", "23-06-2022", "08:30", "09:30"},
    {"7", "RM8.0", "8", "4", "1", "3", "4", "zhen Hou", "20-05-2022", "08:45", "09:00"},
    {"8", "RM10.0", "3", "10", "4", "6", "1", "bob", "10-05-2022", "09:00", "10:00"},
};
```

You can then define your sorting to operate on row indices:

```
// Sort predicate to order by date in reverse
bool SortDateColumn(int a, int b)
{
    return !CompareDate(defaultTickets[a][kDate], defaultTickets[b][kDate]);
}

// Helper to output a ticket
void OutputTicket(int i)
{
    const auto& ticket = defaultTickets.at(i);
    for (const auto& col : ticket)
    {
        cout << col << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

And here's your program using all of the above, tidied up a bit:

```
int main()
{
    string search_user;
    cin >> search_user;

    // Get tickets for user
    vector<int> tickets;
    for (int i = 0; i < defaultTickets.size(); i++)
    {
        if (search_user == defaultTickets[i][kUserName])
        {
            tickets.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    if (tickets.empty())
    {
        cout << "invalid. Please try again" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Sort tickets and output results
    std::sort(tickets.begin(), tickets.end(), SortDateColumn);
    for (int t : tickets)
    {
        OutputTicket(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, now I get why it prints out weirdly. I just tried compiling the code and it works mostly fine, many many thanks for all the helpful pointers on my mistakes! The only error I get is the 'std::string_view’ has not been declared' - does this only work for c++17 onwards?

Comment: Yes, `string_view` was introduced in C++17, as per the documentation that I linked to. If you have an older compiler, you can use the string_view implementation in the Boost libraries. If you can't use either, you could do something dirty like shoving individual characters into the tuple: https://godbolt.org/z/h7j91T48f